# Download a PDF and send the extracted text to another script with Allias(title, description, date...)

Tags: python, pdf, connection, pdf-generation

I've used the module slate, it is based on the pdfminer.

The following script can correctly read articles on pages 1 and 2, but there are many pages and multiple pdf files so the layout may vary pdf a bit varied and sometimes runs an article on the next page, so it does not put down is - so it is not shown well.
There will probably be a for-loop must be built, but I do not know exactly how.
A for-loop is probably what must be built, but I don't know exactly how.

It is also intended that the items are left in a database, but first it must still be sent to a filter script.
So would it be useful if the items could be categorized into title, description, date article, adding date, url and regio_land?

The PDF files:

- [DHS_Daily_Report_2012-08-30](http://www.dhs.gov/sites/default/files/publications/DHS_Daily_Report_2012-08-30.pdf)
- [DHS_Daily_Report_2012-08-29](http://www.dhs.gov/sites/default/files/publications/DHS_Daily_Report_2012-08-29.pdf)
- [DHS_Daily_Report_2012-08-28](http://www.dhs.gov/sites/default/files/publications/DHS_Daily_Report_2012-08-28.pdf)
- [DHS_Daily_Report_2012-08-27](http://www.dhs.gov/sites/default/files/publications/DHS_Daily_Report_2012-08-27.pdf)
- [More daily reports](http://www.dhs.gov/dhs-daily-open-source-infrastructure-report)

---

```
import slate

global artikelIndexStr

with open('report.pdf') as f:
doc = slate.PDF(f)

report = slate.PDF(f)

pdfstring = doc[1] + doc[2] + doc[3] + doc[4] + doc[5] + doc[6] + doc[7] + doc[8] + doc[9] + doc[10] + doc[11] + doc[12] + doc[13] + doc[14] + doc[15] + doc[16] + doc[17] + doc[18] + doc[19] + doc[20]

# print pdfstring

f3 = 'Even iets'        
f3 = pdfstring
temparray = []
temparray2 = []
artikelIndex = 1
artikelIndexStr = ""


while f3 != "":

    f1, f2, f3 = f3.partition("[Return to top]")

    temparray.append(f1)

    print len(temparray)

nieuweIndex = "" + temparray[0]

print nieuweIndex

a1, a2, a3 = nieuweIndex.partition("1. ")
b1, b2, b3 = a3.partition("Source: ")
c1, c2, c3 = b3.partition("2. ")
d1, d2, d3 = c3.partition("Source: ") 
e1, e2, e3 = d3.partition("3.") 
g1, g2, g3 = e3.partition("Source: ") 
h1, h2, h3 = g3.partition("4.") 
i1, i2, i3 = h3.partition("Source: ") 
j1, j2, j3 = i3.partition("5.") 
k1, k2, k3 = h3.partition("Source: ") 
l1, l2, l3 = i3.partition("6.")

print ""
print b1
print ""
print c1
print ""
print d1
print ""
print e1
print ""
print g1
print ""
print h1
print ""
print i1
print ""
print j1
print ""
print k1
print ""
print l1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Patrick. Could you be more explicit about the problem(s) you're facing with your code?

Comment: My problem with the code is that, I get the article not displayed properly(without enters and remove text like 'return to top', 'for another story, see item ... "). And also to get an alliases to 'title, description, date article, adding date, url and regio_land'. so that I can send the articles to an other python script.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for my problem?